# How do I move a local Postgres database to Heroku to make it public? After that how do I connect to the Heroku Postgres database from Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I am currently running a Django application on my local Postgres database. However, I would like to make it remote so that other group members can also read from the database. So how would I migrate my local Postgres database to a Heroku Postgres database? After that, how would I change settings.py in Django to connect to the Heroku Postgres remote database? Thank you!